# How to use the userId in MQCSP for IBM MQ connection authentication in C client

Tags: authentication, ibm-mq

I have a C client to connect to IBM MQ, and I fillin the userid and password in MQCSP as following:

```
        MQCNO Connect_options = {MQCNO_DEFAULT};
        MQCSP   csp = {MQCSP_DEFAULT};
        Connect_options.SecurityParmsPtr = &csp;
        Connect_options.Version = MQCNO_VERSION_5;

        csp.AuthenticationType = MQCSP_AUTH_USER_ID_AND_PWD;
        csp.CSPUserIdPtr = "user2";
        csp.CSPUserIdLength = strlen("user2");
        csp.CSPPasswordPtr = "password";
        csp.CSPPasswordLength = strlen((char*)"password");
```

and then call MQCONNX() to connect the MQ server, run the client with the user "user1", but the server always authenticate the user that running the application "user1".

I setup the MQ server as following:

```
ALTER QMGR CONNAUTH(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS)
DEFINE AUTHINFO(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS) +
    AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS) +
    FAILDLAY(10) +
    CHCKLOCL(OPTIONAL) +
    CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED) +
    ADOPTCTX(YES) 
REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)

define qlocal(HDPARLOCALQUEUE01) replace

define channel(HDPARCHANNEL) +
   chltype(SVRCONN) +
   trptype(TCP) +
   MCAUSER(' ')
alter channel(HDPARCHANNEL) +
  chltype(SVRCONN) +
  MCAUSER(' ')
ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)
```

How can I have the MQ server authenticate the user that provided in the MQCSP?

I have add "ChlauthEarlyAdopt=Y" in qm.ini

Regards,

Comment: What specific version of mq is the queue manager and client running.   Do you see anything in the queue manager's `AMQERR01.LOG`?

Comment: You show a `DEFINE` of the `AUTHINFO` object, but this would fail because that object already exists.   Have you ran a `DISPLAY` against it to be sure `ADOPTCTX(YES)` is actually being set?  Depending on the version of MQ the default is `NO` and would explain what you see.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much JoshMc, I use ALTER replaced DEFINE and it works for me now.

Comment: I'l write up a quick answer please accept it once I post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the IBM MQ queue manager to use the ID you pass in the MQCSP structure for authorization purposes you need to have the `QMGR CONNAUTH`'s `AUTHINFO` object configured with `ADOPTCTX(YES)`.  In your example you are attempting to do this, but it would fail because the object `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS` exists by default.

---

If you want to update an existing object you can not use `DEFINE` to change it unless you accompany this with the `REPLACE` keyword, or you can use the `ALTER` command to accomplish this.

---

I would also recommended to define your own `AUTHINFO` object with the parameters you want, this will prevent future upgrades from overwriting any non-default settings.

For example:

```
DEFINE AUTHINFO(MY.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS) AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS) CHCKLOCL(OPTIONAL) CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED) ADOPTCTX(YES) LIKE(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS)
ALTER QMGR CONNAUTH(MY.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS)
REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)
```

---

I also see you disabled `CHLAUTH`, normally the default `CHLAUTH` rules will not cause any problem, the would only prevent two things:

1. You can not connect to any channel that begins with `SYSTEM`, you are not doing this.
2. You can not connect as a MQ Admin user such as `mqm` or equivalent.  I see your example shows `user2`, if this is a user in the `mqm` group then you would be blocked.

   @MoragHughson has written a nice IBM developerWorks MQdev Blog titled "[Getting going without turning off MQ Security](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/middleware/viewdocument/from-the-archives-getting-going-wi)" that explains how to keep this security enabled and would be a good starting point.